じらつかせる? What kind of verb is this
彼は平坦な顔つきでいながら、瞳の底をじらつかせ
As far there is no verb じらく. So what to make of it? Is it like make darker or? As far I can tell the character is angry at the suggestion of the  main character.

The verb this would be a causative of is じらつく, not じらく. So I believe this kind of definition would be appropriate.

@jogloran That link is blocked in Europe (probably due to the magic of the GDPR). Would be great if you could summarise it in an answer.

That's a full-sized つ, not a sokuon, so imagining a hypothetical conjugated じらく doesn't make sense to me.

The verb you are seeing is じらつく not じらく. -つく after an onomatopoeia is a suffix that means "to get/become ～" (see the 14th definition here). Common examples include:

べたつく = ベタベタする
もたつく = もたもたする
ねばつく = ネバネバする
ぱくつく = パクパクする / パクパクと食べる

Words like ぬめつく, むしゃつく and むずつく are rarer but still easily understood. In your case, じらつく would be interpreted as じらじらする or じらじらとなる. While じらじら by itself is an uncommon mimetic word, it's essentially a variant of じりじり that describes a sense of (slowly) flickering, prickling, or simmering.

彼は瞳の底をじらつかせた
= 彼は瞳の底をじらじら(と)させた
He made the depths of his eyes flicker (with irritation/excitement/etc).

